# where to should write res.send() in node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

In my app I have a category collection that saves the category title with its image ID. The image is saved in another collection with its meta data like path , type and so on. So for retrieving category I should retrieve category image in image collection by its ID and add image path to category object that is retrieved from category collection and send it to client...But I don't know where should I send categories to client?
When I send the response face this error :

```
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (H:\node.js\online-store\app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (H:\node.js\online-store\app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (H:\node.js\online-store\app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (H:\node.js\online-store\app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at H:\node.js\online-store\app\controllers\pcategory.controller.js:123:19
    at H:\node.js\online-store\app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4845:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at H:\node.js\online-store\app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4847:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

This is my code :

```
exports.getAll = async (req, res) => {
     try{
           
        const categories = await ProductCategory.find({});
   
            categories.map(async(category)=>{
             
           await File.findById(category.imageID).exec(function(err,file){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                
                    
                }else if(file) {
                                            
                   category.imagePath = file.file_path;
                   tempCategories.push(category)
                                
                  
               }
                 res.send(tempCategories);
                        
            })
           
           })
         
         
           return res.send(tempCategories); 
            
    }catch {
        res.json(err =>{
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                  err.message || "There is an error in retrieving category"
              });

    })

    }
   
}
```

Comment: cuz, You're trying to call `res.send(tempCategories); ` twise in you code (in lines 16, 27 ) ... hence the message: `
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` - http responce (with http headers of cuz) is already sent to client, and you trying again ...

Comment: res.send will terminate the function like return does so you don't need to return from this function. If you remove res.send from the map, this error will disappear. You probably have to build up the return value and then send it after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that nothing in your code is waiting for the asynchronous operations you're doing in your `map` callback to complete, so it does the `res.send` at the end right away — and then does `res.send` again within the `map` callback later when the async operations complete. Instead, wait for them to finish and send the result.

Also, you're using `res.send` where I suspect you want `res.json`, and using `res.json` later incorrectly (it doesn't take a callback).

See comments:

```
exports.getAll = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Get the categories
        const categories = await ProductCategory.find({});
        // Get the files for the categories, wait for the result
        const result = await Promise.all(categories.map(async (category) => {
            const file = await File.findById(category.imageID).exec();
            // You probably can't modify the `category` object, so let's create
            // and return a new object
            return {...category, imagePath: file.file_path};
        }));
        // Send the result converted to JSON
        return res.json(tempCategories);
    } catch (err) { // Accept the error
        // Send an error response
        res.status(500).json({
            message: err.message || "There is an error in retrieving category"
        });
    }
};
```

---

Side note: Your original code was using `map` without using the array it creates. That's an antipattern (sadly it seems to be one someone somewhere is teaching). I wrote up why and what to do instead [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/). (In my update to your code, I still use `map`, but I use the array it creates, passing it to `Promise.all` so we can wait for all those promises to settle.)

Comment: Thank you for your complete guidance. I wrote your code but faced with this : "message": "Cannot read property 'file_path' of null"

Comment: @Gandom - That's unrelated to the question. It tells you that the promise from `File.findById(category.imageID).exec()` was fulfilled with the value `null` (which I'm guessing means "none found with that ID"). If you need to handle that case, check `file` for `null` and handle that case in the code.

Comment: Thank you so much...your help saved me a lot... my problem was solved